# DATEPARSE in Tableau turning all months into January

Tags: csv, tableau-api

I have been connecting Tableau to a csv data source.  I have two date columns.  When I tell Tableau they are date columns it imports the entirety of both columns as Nulls.  I tried to import them as strings and create a calculated date column out of each with DATEPARSE.

I ran this ([Close Time] is the string from the CSV)

```
DATEPARSE("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss",[Close Time])
```

and named the column "Close_Time_DT"

The result was:

Close Time

1. '05/30/2013  11:20:50'
2. '05/30/2013  18:01:53'
3. '06/05/2013  02:02:49'

Close_Time_DT

1. '1/30/2013 11:20:50 AM'
2. '1/30/2013 6:01:53 PM'
3. '1/5/2013 2:02:49 AM'

Clearly this is wrong, I tried also with

```
DATEPARSE("m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss", [Close Time])
```

and got the same result.
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: try DATEPARSE("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss",[Close Time])

Comment: Tried that, now getting '06/18/2013 17:02:28' in the csv converted into '7/1/2013 6:41:46 PM' in Tableau.  Additional examples:

07/01/2013  16:02:38 ---> 7/1/2013 6:42:28 PM
06/27/2013  13:25:41 ---> 7/2/2013 7:18:32 PM
12/04/2013  05:03:21 ---> 12/4/2013 5:14:01 AM

Comment: `DATEPARSE("M/dd/yyy  H:mm:ss",[Open Time])`

This works, why, I do not really understand.

Comment: Small letter m i used for Minutes and Capital letter M is used for Month. MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss should return the correct value. Not sure if something else is wrong. try DATEPARSE("MMM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss",[Close Time])  it should return the month Name instead of month number.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My source csv format for dates was date/month/year (07/01/2015). When I used Dateparse function i first entered it as

```
DATEPARSE("dd/mm/yyyy",[ServDate])
```

but it did not properly handle the month and would make it July or in one case put all the dates in the same month (january). 
What finally worked was to use:

```
DATEPARSE("d/M,y",[ServDate])
```